# Warnings for bad XML comments - How to enable?

Tags: delphi, warnings, compiler-warnings, xml-comments, compiler-directives

I want warnings for bad XML comments. They're turned on in Project Options and there are no Compiler Directives inside the unit with the bad xml comments, but I'm not getting any warnings. What else could hide them?

Günther the Beautiful gave the right hint, see comment below.

Comment: Can you give us an example of a bad XML comment?

Comment: Keep in mind that "build XML documentation" is entirely disabled by default (Compile Options) so XML comment directives are moot in this case.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful: That is what I looked for, thanks! Unfortunately, I cannot mark a comment as an answer...